# How to print from Chrome on mobile web app?

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-chrome, printing

I have a web app where users can create invoices.  I would like users to able to print tags/labels that the web app generates directly from their phones.

I will only be supporting the latest phones.  A Chrome Mobile & Android **only** solution is perfectly acceptable.

I've looked into Google Cloud Printing but, and please correct me if I'm wrong, the `gmail` account must be the same for the user and the printer in order to print.  I would need ~5 users to be able to print from the same printer.

What are the best practicing regarding mobile printing from web apps?

Comment: Hi Raphael, by any chance were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Cooshal I have not, but we scrapped the project pretty quickly after starting an investigation